# Redefine numbering of frames in export animation

Tags: animation, export

I have a single Blender Scene that consists of lots of *scenes* (in the movie/theatrical sense), so scene 1 consists of frames 1-1000, scene 2: 1001-3000, etc.

But I'd like to redefine the numbering when I export an animation as frames. I'd like to export scene 2 as s2_0001.png-s2_2000.png, but blender insists on using the frame number in the timeline, so it'll always be s2_1001.png-s2_3000.png.

The problem with this is if I decide to change the length of scene 1, then my numbering for scene 2 completely changes, so if I need to re-render any part of scene 2, the number for every single frame is different.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: I would assume you will need to use python in the file name slot. How to do it is beyond me. Maybe add python to tags.